# how to use props to change className ? (reactjs/css)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't succeed by defining a function
and call this function below by just changing className for each element ..

Here is the code:

```
const ProgressBar = (props)=>{
    return(
        <div className={props.styleName}>
            <div className={classes.ProgressBarGradient}>
                <div className={classes.GradientHider}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const GridContent = (props)=>{
    return (
        <div className={classes.Container}>
            <h3 className={classes.Title1}>progress vs target</h3>
            <h3 className={classes.Title2}>weekly goal</h3>
            <h3 className={classes.Title3}>monthly goal</h3>
            <ProgressBar styleName="ProgressBar1"></ProgressBar>
        </div>
    );
}
```

What I want is to change only the className of the first div when I call the function below.
Thank you so much :)

PS: I use css modules so when I call my class I usually do className={classes.className}

Comment: Do you want to use dynamic `classes`? btw where are the classes? is that material UI?

Comment: yes, @b3hr4d, I imported "classes" from './path/file.module.CSS' because I use the modules to define className

Comment: So you want to change classes of the first div to `classes.ProgressBar1` if you pass that?

Comment: exactly, I tried to do it with props, but I was not sure it is the good way. Then I want to insert more <ProgressBar/> elements but with a different class for the first div

Comment: try this `classes[props.styleName]`

Comment: in the ProgressBar function or in the GridContent one ?

Comment: <div className={classes[props.styleName]}>

Comment: Worked Perfectly. Thank you so much

Comment: ill add on answer then maybe be solve other people in future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ProgressBar use this :

```
<div className={classes[props.styleName]}>
```